# MySQL : Order by 2 fields

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a list of products, and each has a price. I wish to show the most expensive product, and if 2 products or more tie, then I wish to order by their name. Doing this doesn't seem to produce the results I want:

```
ORDER BY cost DESC, product_name
```

What is the syntax which I am looking for?

Comment: It looks like you have the syntax correct. Are you sure the first result is producing duplicates?

Comment: Your syntax looks fine to me.  What output do you see?

Comment: could you post query results that illustrate this clause not working as expected?

Answer (score 6):

This works fine:

```
use test;

create table products (cost decimal(15,2), product_name varchar(50));

insert into products values (14.50, 'b product');
insert into products values (14.50, 'a product');
insert into products values (15.50, 'c product');

select * from products order by cost desc, product_name
```

Returns:

```
15.50, 'c product'
14.50, 'a product'
14.50, 'b product'
```

Answer (score 4):

where's the problem?

```
ORDER BY cost DESC, product_name
```

will order by `cost desc` and then by `product_name asc`. What type of unexpected behaviour are you experiencing?